# ESlint and the object spread operator inside a function or a const, why is complaining?

Tags: javascript, eslint

[image: ESLint]

> Parsing error: Unexpected token ...

Honestly, I can't understand why ESlint  is adding the error for the first `console.log` statement and not for the second:

```
const generateCss = () => {
  console.log({...{foo: 'bar'}});
};

function bar() {
  console.log({...{foo: 'bar'}});
}
```

Is there any explanation or it's my fault?

ESlint (v7.2.0) configuration:

```
{
  "extends": "eslint:recommended",
    "env": {
      "es6": true,
      "node": true,
      "mocha": true
    },
    "parserOptions": {
      "ecmaVersion": 6,
      "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "rules": {
      "array-bracket-spacing": "warn",
      "arrow-parens": ["warn", "as-needed"],
      "arrow-spacing": "warn",
      "brace-style": "warn",
      "comma-spacing": "warn",
      "computed-property-spacing": "warn",
      "consistent-return": "warn",
      "curly": ["warn", "all"],
      "eol-last": "warn",
      "eqeqeq": "warn",
      "func-call-spacing": "warn",
      "indent": ["warn", 2, {
        "SwitchCase": 1
      }],
      "key-spacing": ["warn"],
      "new-cap": "warn",
      "new-parens": "warn",
      "no-multiple-empty-lines": ["warn", {
        "max": 1
      }],
      "no-nested-ternary": "warn",
      "no-return-assign": ["warn", "always"],
      "no-trailing-spaces": "warn",
      "no-unneeded-ternary": "warn",
      "no-var": "warn",
      "object-curly-spacing": ["warn", "always"],
      "padded-blocks": ["warn", "never"],
      "prefer-const": "warn",
      "quote-props": ["warn", "as-needed"],
      "quotes": ["warn", "single"],
      "semi-spacing": "warn",
      "space-before-blocks": ["warn", "always"],
      "space-before-function-paren": ["warn", {
        "anonymous": "always",
        "asyncArrow": "always",
        "named": "never"
      }],
      "space-in-parens": "warn",
      "space-infix-ops": ["warn", {
        "int32Hint": true
      }],
      "space-unary-ops": "warn",
      "spaced-comment": ["warn", "always"],
      "yoda": ["warn", "always", {
        "onlyEquality": true
      }]
    }
}
```

Comment: [You have to set the ES version to 8, because Object spread wasn't introduced until ES2018](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/10307)

Comment: Your using the spread syntax, try setting `"ecmaVersion": 9,`

Comment: "*Honestly, I can't understand why ESlint is adding the error for the first console.log statement and not for the second:*" for the record, it's because there was a parsing error, so it stops. If you remove the error (e.g., but removing that line), you'd get another parsing error in the other function.

Comment: @Pointy  Seems odd I know, but 2018 in ESLint is 9..

Comment: @Pointy seems to 9, as suggested. Please answer the question so I can accept it, seems working.

Comment: @Keith since ES6 was in 2015, it's been off by one. Honestly, I'd rather TC39 wait a year without releasing a spec so it syncs up. Makes it super hard to track otherwise. Or they can release a non-sequential spec one year, e.g., for 2020 it could be named ES-Corona and then just get back to ES11 in 2021. An alternative is to start producing multiple specs per year until they catch up to the years, so in 2025 we'd have ES25 or so.

Comment: @VLAZ It's not off by one. The year number and the release version are off by 2009 :-)

Comment: @Bergi fair point... Maybe instead we can just move to a new calendar that has year number = ES spec number. Easier to keep track that way. :P

Comment: @gremo hello! may I know which theme and font are you using on the screenshot provided?

Comment: @Klaha did you received my mail? cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment to the answer, Object spread was introduced in ES2018.

So, if you're using more modern ES features, remember to update the `"ecmaVersion"` inside your config for this.  In this case, you need `"ecmaVersion": 9`.

For a reference here is the full list:

```
ES3 -> 3
ES5 -> 5
ES2015 -> 6
ES2016 -> 7
ES2017 -> 8
ES2018 -> 9
ES2019 -> 10
ES2020 -> 11
```